# How to get the type of an entry in a GEOMETRY data type column

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

A column of the data type GEOMETRY can hold either POLYGON, LINESTRING or POINT type data. Is it possible to get the type of the contained geo data, or for example only select rows of a specific type?

Sure, one could use AsText() and regex to get the part before the brackets, but that would be a very unperformant approach to this... Or the data type could be saved into a separate column... But isn't there a built-in function I might just have missed in the MySQL docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're looking for [ST_GeometryType](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gis-general-property-functions.html#function_st-geometrytype).

Comment: Perfect, thanks - I must have been blind, now I found it in the docs.